# Ubuntu 20.04 Server UFW does not activate automatically

Tags: server, systemd, firewall, ufw

Lately, I've noticed that UFW is inactive until I activate it manually.

I've run `ufw enable` multiple times, checked that `ufw.service` is active, but it still does not start on boot.

Output of `systemctl list-unit-files | grep -i ufw`

```
ufw.service                                enabled         enabled
```

Output of `systemctl status ufw`

```
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ufw.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Sat 2022-09-24 12:15:01 +03; 1min 26s ago
       Docs: man:ufw(8)
    Process: 388 ExecStart=/lib/ufw/ufw-init start quiet (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 388 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Sep 24 12:15:01 alienus-server systemd[1]: Finished Uncomplicated firewall.
Warning: journal has been rotated since unit was started, output may be incomplete.
```

I've tried re-enabling `ufw.service` and it did not work:

```
Removed /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/ufw.service.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/ufw.service → /lib/systemd/system/ufw.service.
```

Outputs of everything right after a boot:[image: terminal footage]

Additional info: After purging and reinstalling UFW, both with copying old configurations and manually reconfiguring, it is still not working as intended. And even though it was active when it booted, a couple of hours later it got deactivated again. So in order to keep it active, I've added a cronjob to reactivate it every 30 minutes.

Where else can I check for the reason that it does not start automatically? What is `Warning: journal has been rotated since unit was started, output may be incomplete.`?

Comment: `systemctl enable ufw` - have you tried this?

Comment: @DankyNanky yes, I've tried disabling and enabling, re-enabling. Systemd service starts correctly (I can't see any error due to journal rotation) but ufw is still inactive after every boot.

Comment: According to your output of "systemctl status ufw.service" it says active though?

Comment: @petep yes, even though the ufw.service is active, the ufw itself is inactive. that's the strange part, that i'm trying to solve

Comment: State active (exited) means that systemd has successfully run the set of commands but that it does not know there is a daemon to monitor. I suspect this to be the case for UFW service.

Comment: How do you know the firewall is inactive? Does `pgrep ufw` show it's running? Do you just have no firewall rules? What does `sudo ufw status numbered` show? What does a firewall scan (like [ShieldsUp](https://www.grc.com/shieldsup)) show?

Comment: Journal rotation is pruning of log files, that message just means housekeeping ran to tidy up your log files since the service was loaded. `journalctl -g ufw` will grep those logs for "ufw".

Answer (score -2):

As a mitigation until I can gather further info about this issue, I've created a systemd-service to manually enable ufw.

ufw2.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Uncomplicated firewall 2
Documentation=man:ufw(8)
After=ufw.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/etc/ufw/ufw.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

ufw.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

sleep 10
ufw enable
```

(10-second sleep is to be sure that the main ufw service has started and settled)

Addition: I've noticed that ufw got deactivated while the server was open for a couple of hours. So as a second mitigation, I've added a cron job to run it every 30 minutes.

```
*/30 * * * * systemctl restart ufw2
```

Comment: The “exited” UFW is still working, so this answer does do nothing.

Comment: Without this additional enabling of UFW, the firewall is still inactive after a boot. In my case, this is the systemd-service that actually activates the firewall. So, this answer **does do someting**

Answer (score -2):

UFW daemon will start automatically even if you don't enable it. You should run `ufw enable` to enable it. The below screenshot shows the difference.

(As it's a complete rewrite, I think it's better to re-post instead of editing.)

[image]

Comment: Yes, I know that it starts automatically with the service, but somehow ufw does not get activated with the service or something disables it right after it has been activated. My answer, the second UFW service and the cron job, does this automatically since the UFW should **never be inactive on a public server**. That is the problem I'm trying to solve.

Comment: Again, similar to your last answer, this does not contribute anything to the question. The answers you gave are already discussed. Both in the question and the comment section.