# ModemManager can't start as a service, but manual start works

Tags: systemd, services

For a while now, I haven't been able to start the ModemManager service.

```
➜  ~ systemctl status ModemManager.service
× ModemManager.service - Modem Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ModemManager.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2022-09-30 19:39:32 CEST; 21s ago
    Process: 23668 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/ModemManager (code=exited, status=127)
   Main PID: 23668 (code=exited, status=127)
        CPU: 26ms

Sep 30 19:39:32 tsch systemd[1]: Starting Modem Manager...
Sep 30 19:39:32 tsch systemd[1]: ModemManager.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a
Sep 30 19:39:32 tsch systemd[1]: ModemManager.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 30 19:39:32 tsch systemd[1]: Failed to start Modem Manager.
```

However, manually starting ModemManager works fine:

```
➜  ~ sudo ModemManager
ModemManager[25946]: <info>  ModemManager (version 1.16.6) starting in system bus...
...
```

The service file (`/etc/systemd/system/dbus-org.freedesktop.ModemManager1.service`) looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Modem Manager
After=polkit.service
Requires=polkit.service

[Service]
Type=dbus
BusName=org.freedesktop.ModemManager1
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/ModemManager
StandardError=null
Restart=on-abort
CapabilityBoundingSet=CAP_SYS_ADMIN CAP_NET_ADMIN
ProtectSystem=true
ProtectHome=true
PrivateTmp=true
RestrictAddressFamilies=AF_NETLINK AF_UNIX AF_QIPCRTR
NoNewPrivileges=true
User=root

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=dbus-org.freedesktop.ModemManager1.service
```

Any ideas on what is wrong here? Running on Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: I have a similar [issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1432037/ubuntu-20-04-server-ufw-does-not-start-automatically) and mitigation, but with the UFW. These might be a similar issue if it's a systemd problem, but if it isn't, it's just a weird coincidence with two separate programs.

Comment: I'm also running Ubuntu 22.04, and my ModemManager is version 1.18.6. Could you try updating your packages with `sudo apt full-upgrade` to get the latest version, and report back?

Comment: Version 1.16.6 is the "Impish" version, so it seems you may have several old packages on your system. Upgrading packages to the latest version is important for troubleshooting errors.

Comment: @ArturMeinild Thanks for your suggestion!
I checked my versions and found out that I have *two* versions of modem manager installed (one in `/usr/local/sbin` and one in `/usr/sbin`). The version I started manually worked, but was a different one than the one that was started by systemd...

Comment: I think this explains the problem. You should remove the "unofficial" version, and upgrade to the latest official version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have two different versions of `ModemManager` installed.

I would suggest that you first remove the "unofficial" version (located in `/usr/local/sbin`) in whatever way fits how you installed it (I don't know what you did).

Then, run `sudo apt full-upgrade` to upgrade your packages to the latest version, including a potential upgrade to `ModemManager`.

If versioning conflicts still exist, you could force a reinstall of the latest `ModemManager` with this command:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall modemmanager
```

This should hopefully fix any issues with the `ModemManager` service.

Comment: Please let me know if this solved the issue for you ..

Comment: The thing is that the "unofficial" version is the one that works, while the official (1.18.6) one doesn't. But that will be the topic of another question...